# Localizing the quotient at a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I was reading in Dummit and Foote when I came across this statement I don't believe it is true.

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain (noetherian, integrally closed, domain of dimension 1). They say given a prime ideal $P\neq 0$ then
>   $$R/P^{m}\cong R_{P}/P^{m}R_{P}.$$

Why is this true? Shouldn't we get 
$$ (R/P^{m})_{\overline{P}}\cong R_{P}/P^{m}R_{P}?$$

I don't see why when we localize $R/P^{m}$ at the image of $P$ nothing changes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Domain of dimension $=1$, then $P$ is maximal.

Comment: Maybe $P\neq0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $M$, then $A\simeq A_M$. In your case $A=R/P^m$ is local since $P$ is the only prime containing $P^m$.